# Media query changing Div Background color but not its width?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I already searched and tried solutions but did not work for me.

My div is,

```
 <div id="test" class="col-4">
            <a class="nav-link py-0" href="~/MyDevices/Index">
                <img src="~/Images/logo.png" width="75" />
                <strong class="h4 text-white">
                    Title is here for Application
                </strong>
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Title breaks down on small device but i manually change its div class to "col-6" it works fine.
I am using media query to change col-4 to col-6 its not working but i can change div background color.

My media query is,

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #test  {
        width: 50% !important;
        background-color: aliceblue;
    }
}
```

my media query is inside bootstrap.css

if i use .col in media query after #test than it does not call this media query no BG color.

How to change div width ?

hopes for you response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 uses flex so if you are using that you should change width to flex like this

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #test  {
        flex: 50% !important;
        max-width: 50% !important;
        background-color: aliceblue;
    }
}
```

But you can use bootstrap for this by just adding col-md-6 to the element

```
 <div id="test" class="col-4 col-md-6">
```

Comment: i am using Bootstrap 3 should i also try class="col-4 col-md-6" ?

Comment: yeah for bootstrap 3 thats the same

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: Great, no problem glad I could help! :)

Comment: if you dont mind can you tell what is this col-md-6 doing ?

Comment: I've send you a link explaining the bootstrap classes w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: i am not wrong col-md-6 change the width of div media query still not effecting its width ?

Comment: col-md-6 is the media query to change it width what you are saying is: "col-4" make the element 4/12 width of the parent (translates to width: 33.33333%). "col-md-6" when on the md breakpoint (larger than 768 px) make the width 6/12 (translates to width: 50%)

Comment: Oooo ok thats great i also make changes on bid device with but i have to use max-width instead of width. thanks